Kali Linux disc file not showing in storage settings of virtual box

I am doing a course on ethical hacking.
I have downloaded the latest version of VirtualBox and kali linux. I have also extracted the kali linux file using the 7-zip app.
When I started it on VirtualBox, it showed "aborted" and now it is showing

"The native API dil was not found"

after trying to start it.
I did some research and got to know that it was because the storage of settings was empty.
I tried to choose the kali linux disk file but it's showing

"No items match your search"

though there is a file which should match the search.
Please tell me the underlying problem and its solution.

The extracted files are 1) The description of the virtual machine that can be loaded into virtualbox 2) the virtual hard drive. You should import the virtual machine settings into virtualbox and might have to relink the virtual hdd. Your virtualbox is asking for an 'optical drive image', which comes as an .ISO file and typically is the installation cd/dvd for the operating system its asking for. Either look in your course material on how to make use of the virtualbox image or ask a tutor for help for the specific needs for your course.

Ok, well the course is on you tube and that too 2 years old. I will try your suggestion and see if it works.
